# How to Measure Distance and Area using Openlayers3 with GeoExt3 and ExtJs6?

Tags: openlayers-3, extjs6, geoext3

I need to add the measurement tool for my GIS Portal.Is anyone know how to measure distance and area in Openlayers3 with GeoExt3 and ExtJs6?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is an **example** that shows how to implement a measure tool **in OpenLayers 3**, see:

http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/measure.html

How such a tool is implemented greatly depends on the application itself and the other libraries available around it.  For example, you're using GeoExt3 and ExtJS6.  You could **create the tool** as a **GeoExt3** component and **contribute** it with Pull Request.  See: https://geoext.github.io/geoext3/ (Now: Get Involved!)